# Tools for collaboration between units

Tags: collaboration, support-tracker

I am the first point of contact for customer support, i need to forward the customers' feedback to any of three other units (Production, Marketing and Finance) depending on the type of feedback. These customer feedback may include screenshots (images).

Can you recommend any software tools for this type of collaboration?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with Markus in saying that project/task management tools would be the best choice in this case. Depending on what the other teams are already using, you could do one of two:

- Add in new tasks into their existing boards and tag them as Feedback
- Create a separate board for feedback and add in the tasks there, separating them with different lanes or tagging them based on the department- Production, Finance, etc.

This will allow you to note down everything easily, make sure the information is relayed to a specific department and then come back to check if it has been solved. (as you can track the progress of each task)
If you do not currently use a project management solution and are looking for one, my recommendations would be [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com). I found it easy to use and you can add various details to tasks, as well as screenshots.

Good luck in your search!

Answer (score 0):

You could use any Kanban Tool.

You could create a board for each unit. A Kanban Board is like a table with columns showing your workflow (for example TODO, In Progress, Done). Each column can contain cards/tasks. Each card can handle your information and uploads.

One of the most famous Kanban Boards is [Trello](https://trello.com/).
If you are looking for a more GDPR compliant solution you can give [ARRI Webgates Kanban Boards](https://arriwebgate.com/kanban-boards) a try.

There was nothing in my professional and private life that could not be represented with Kanban ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per you are asking specifically for feedback management, [traggr feedback management](https://www.traggr.com) could be a good choice for you.
It allows you to assign tags to each feedback topic you collect so you could assign tags like `production`, `marketing`, `finance` to the respective feedback when you collect it from your customers.

Teammates from the other departments can then filter the feedback to their specific tag, e.g. people from `marketing` will then only see feedback for `marketing`.
You still have all your feedback in one place but other departments can focus on what's only relevant to them.

Disclaimer: I am part of the traggr team. If you miss anything for your specific case, let us know.